# Expr eval within Julia module gives UndefVarError

Tags: dataframe, julia, metaprogramming

I'm able to run the following code just fine and it provides the expected result:

```
julia> using DataFrames, DataFramesMeta

julia> expr = "2*:a+:b"
"2*:a+:b"

julia> df = DataFrame(a=[1,2],b=[3,4])
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b     
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      3
   2 │     2      4

julia> eval(Meta.parse("@transform(df, " * join(collect(":res" => expr), " = ") * ")"))
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      res   
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      3      5
   2 │     2      4      8
```

However, this fails when done inside a module.

```
julia> module foo
           using DataFrames, DataFramesMeta
           function bar()
               expr = "2*:a+:b"
               df = DataFrame(a=[1,2],b=[3,4])
               eval(Meta.parse("@transform(df, " * join(collect(":res" => expr), " = ") * ")"))
           end
       end
Main.foo

julia> foo.bar()
ERROR: UndefVarError: df not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ ~/.julia/packages/DataFramesMeta/BkRtJ/src/macros.jl:1363
 [2] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:368 [inlined]
 [3] eval
   @ ./REPL[9]:1 [inlined]
 [4] bar()
   @ Main.foo ./REPL[9]:6
 [5] top-level scope
   @ REPL[10]:1
```

I imagine this is possible scope issue, and tried to be explicit by using `foo.df` instead of `df` in the function call, but without success.

Would anyone know how what is preventing `df` from being recognized as a defined variable here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Bogumil said `eval` totally does not look like a recommended way to write your code.

However if your goal is learning macros this is the correct code:

```
module Foo2
    using DataFrames, DataFramesMeta
    function bar()
        expr = "2*:a+:b"
        df = DataFrame(a=[1,2],b=[3,4])
        code = quote
            @transform($df, :res = $(Meta.parse(expr)))
        end
        eval(code)
    end
end
```

Now you can run:

```
julia> Foo2.bar()
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      res
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      3      5
   2 │     2      4      8
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that `eval` is evaluated in global scope, as you can read in its docstring:

> Evaluate an expression in the global scope of the containing module.

In general using `Meta.parse` and `eval` is highly not recommended. Can you please explain the problem you are trying to solve as there is probably another way to handle it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm creating an application where the user inputs a formula to perform simple operations on data residing in a dataframe. The user (singular) is trusted to not try to inject code to be evaluated, which is the obvious danger. Otherwise yes you'd want to sanitize inputs.
I used to have this code in python, where I was using a modified pyparsing/fourfn.py to evaluate simple arithmetic operations and apply to dataframe columns.
Ideally I'd want to do the same in Julia (ie parsing a restricted grammar) but there doesnt seem to be a simple and mature package for that. Meta does the job.

Comment: Then you can consider generating a string with the whole definition of the function and doing `Meta.parse` and `eval` on it. I think it would be simplest (apart from Przemysław proposed).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This seems more complex than say Przemysław's solution, and doesn't alleviate the injection concern. I will probably go with Przemysław's solution until I can find a way to parse/eval a restricted and simple grammar.